# Error loading .h5 model from Google Drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I am confused. The file exists in the directory, I have checked it with 2 methods from Python. Why can't I load the `model`? Is there any other method to load the `.h5` file? I think this screenshot will explain this all.
[image: error snippet]

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
import os.path

model_path = "./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code Skripsi/Epoch-Train/300-0.0001-train-file.h5"

print(os.path.exists(model_path))

if os.path.isfile(model_path):
    print ("File exist")
else:
    print ("File not exist")

model = load_model(model_path)
```

File in the Drive folder: 
[image]

In response to Experience_In_AI's answer, I made the file look like this:
[image] 
and this is the structure: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem reproduced and solved:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model

try:
    #model_path="drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code_Skripsi/Epoch-Train/300-0.001-train-file.h5"
    model_path=r".\drive\MyDrive\1117002_Code_Skripsi\Epoch-Train\300-0.001-train-file.h5"
    model=load_model(model_path)
except:
    model_path=r".\drive\MyDrive\1117002_Code_Skripsi\Epoch-Train\experience_in_ai.h5"
    model=load_model(model_path)
    print("...it seems to be better to use more simple naming with the .h5 file!")

model.summary()
```

...note that the .h5 files in the simulated location are exact copies but having only different name.

Comment: by this code, do you mean that I should change my filename?

Comment: I've tried your solution, renaming my file on Google Drive, and this still does not work

Comment: Please show your command exactly when making this renaming.

Comment: I use the exact same code as you provided. Should I do something with my file in Drive? Sorry, but I still can't fully understand your given solution.

Comment: got this error: ```OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code_Skripsi/Epoch-Train/300-0.0001-train-file.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code_Skripsi/Epoch-Train/experience_in_ai.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}```

Comment: I made 2 files. Please see my updated post

Comment: Looks like it's adding an extra layer to your path `{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`. Maybe try just having the folder name (make sure it contains a single model file) i.e. `load_model('.../Epoch-Train/')`

Comment: @ML_Engine error again :( message: ```OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./drive/MyDrive/1117002_Code_Skripsi/Epoch-Train//{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}```. Notice the ```//```

Comment: Try without `/` at the end? `load_model('.../Epoch-Train')`

Comment: Result are the same. What else can I change?

Answer (score -2):

I think this will work :

```
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```

Comment: this doesn't work. This is the same as what I've tried to do.